# Different formats for the wave

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

Introductory Physics textbooks give the wave   either as

$$y = A\sin\left(2 \pi \left(\frac{t}{T} - \frac{x}{\lambda}\right)\right)$$

or as

$$y =A \sin \left(2 \pi \left(\frac{x}{\lambda}- \frac{t}{T}\right)\right)$$

Would someone explain please if and how these two versions are consistent?

Comment: Where did you see the first one?

Comment: Note that [wave equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation) is a protected technical term which means something different. (Specifically, the partial differential equation which governs the motion of the wave.) The objects you're worried about here are called *waveforms*.

Comment: @ Zebra As Emilio pointed out, these are not the wave equation but particular solutions of the wave equation.

Comment: I didn't: someone edited out the slashes or soliduses between the t and T and between the x and lambda!

Answer (score 3):

Just by seeing dimensions, You can see the first one is wrong. As $tT$ has a unit of sec$^2$ and $x\lambda$ has a unit of length square.

The second one is correct expression for the [sinusoidal wav](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave)e.

---

Edit: Seems like there has been some confusion! Maybe I have edited wrongly OP's post by mistake. And I apologize for that.

---

Both of the waves are sinusoidal waves but there is a phase difference between them. If I rewrite the waves (using the variable $k$ and $\omega$ as it much simpler to write )

$$y= A\sin(kx-\omega t) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ (1)$$
$$y= A\sin(kx-\omega t +\pi) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ (2)$$

So We can see that the waves have a phase difference of $\pi$ radians. Apart from this waves are same.

I don't what OP meant by consistent but both the equation satisfies one dimensional wave equation.

$$\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial x^2}=\frac{1}{v^2}\frac{\partial^2 y}{\partial t^2}$$

Comment: Not sure if it was you, (this is my first post on this site) but someone edited out two / signs in my original.

Comment: @AlZebra  Please find the edit to the answer. Pardon me.

Answer (score 1):

Any equation that has a solution with harmonic components will contain terms that look like this $$\text{wave} \propto \sin( \text{angle})$$ where $\text{angle}$ is a dimensionless quantity. There are many options for classical waves, for example

$$ \begin{aligned}
  \text{angle} & = 2\pi \tfrac{x - c t}{\lambda} \\
  \text{angle} & = \tfrac{2\pi}{T} \left( \tfrac{x}{c}-t \right) \\
  \text{angle} & = 2\pi \left(\tfrac{x}{\lambda} -\tfrac{t}{T} \right)  \\
\end{aligned}$$

All of the above are valid solutions to the wave equation, and which one to use depends on what quantities are known. From the three quantities, $c$ is the wave speed, $\lambda$ is the wavelength, $T$ is period, two are needed on each solution.

Finally, the equation $\text{angle} = 2\pi ( t T - x \lambda)$ *must be incorrect* because angle must be dimensionless.